# Regex: remove whitespaces but not from < > tag

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

i've been struggling with regexp for ages..what i need is to remove all the whitespaces from a string, but not from < tags > (eg. an a href tag or a img src tag must have whitespaces).

I'm doing it in PHP and i'm trying different solutions (i'm a total noob with regexp, and this is so confusing to me).
this is the portion of my code so far:

```
$text=$_POST["text"];
$pattern = '(\<.+?\>)|\s'; 
$replace = '';
echo preg_replace( $pattern, $replace, $text );
```

what's wrong with this? :(

Comment: Can you post an example $_POST value?

Comment: Yes, like " foo fo o o o oo <img src="foo.png">" the output should be "foofoooooo <img src="foo.png">"

Comment: What doe it give. Also some online regex tools might help you with this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you forgot the delimiters around your regex. Then, the regex `/(\<.+?\>)|\s/` matches a tag or whitespace, so your `preg_replace()` replaces *either one* with the empty string.

Manipulating HTML with regexes is difficult, to say the least. If you can be sure that you won't have any `<`s and `>`s anywhere in your file except for where they delimit a tag, you can look for whitespace where the closest bracket (if any) is an opening one:

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '/\s+     # Match one or more whitespace characters
    (?!       # but only if it is impossible to match...
     [^<>]*   # any characters except angle brackets
     >        # followed by a closing bracket.
    )         # End of lookahead
    /x', 
    '', $subject);
```

Comment: that's a good point, maybe would be better using something like /(\<img.+?\>)|\s/ because i need to preserve the whitespaces within the img tag

Comment: This regex preserves all whitespaces in between "<" and ">" as you want. And it also outputs strings like this `"<p class="myclass">test my string</p>if this > that"` as `"<p class="myclass">testmystring</p>if this >that"`. If you don't have any "<" or ">"'s in your string, it's OK to use it.

Comment: I still couldn't put that `(?!` to the right place though :) upvoted.

Comment: thank you, both solutions are working (i have to edit to make it work only on <img > :))

Comment: @Simone: You won't have much luck there. This would require variable-length look*behind* assertions, and PHP doesn't support these. This regex here relies on look*ahead* assertions, and when you look ahead in a tag, you obviously can't see what's at the start of the tag (in this case, the tag's name).

Answer (score 2):

a non regex solution.

```
function remove_non_tag_space($text){
    $len = strlen($text);
    $out = "";
    $in_tag=false;
    for($i=0;$i<$len; $i++){
        $c = $text[$i];
        if($c=='<')
            $in_tag=true;
        elseif($c=='>')
            $in_tag=false;

        $out .= $c==" "? ($in_tag? $c: ""): $c;
    }
    return $out;
}
```

See sample here http://ideone.com/oI0DI

Comment: thank you, both solutions are working (i have to edit to make it work only on <img > :)

Comment: A non-regex solution is usually faster than regex.

Comment: @Simone: Faster/slower probably doesn't matter here (and I wouldn't be so sure that regex is slower). What matters is that regex is *not the right tool* for this. I'm sure shiplu.mokadd.im can help you to refine this code to handle only image tags. Then you should accept his answer.