# preg_replace limit issue, handling array values

Tags: php, preg-replace

I've been working with the [Sphider](http://www.sphider.eu/) search engine for an internal website, we need to be able to quickly search for contact details in exported .htm(l) files.

```
$fulltxt = ereg_replace("[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,3})", "<a href=\"mailto:\\0\">\\0</a>", $fulltxt);
```

I am replacing e-mail addresses with a convenient mailto: link so users can open Outlook straight from the search results.

However,

```
while (preg_match("/[^\>](".$change.")[^\<]/i", " ".$fulltxt." ", $regs)) {
    $fulltxt = preg_replace("/".$regs[1]."/i", "<b>".$regs[1]."</b>", $fulltxt);
    }
```

It replaces all matches in the search results with bold tags, which resuts into the tags been included in Outlook's 'To...' field. It looks something like this in HTML (thanks *Yuriy*):

```
<a href="mailto:<b>name</b>.surname@domain"><b>name</b>.surname@domain</a>
```

I have tried adding a value to the 'limit' parameter:

```
while (preg_match("/[^\>](".$change.")[^\<]/i", " ".$fulltxt." ", $regs)) {
    $fulltxt = preg_replace("/".$regs[1]."/i", "<b>".$regs[1]."</b>", $fulltxt, 1);
    }
```

Supposingly this should be the solution to my problem by simply replacing only the first occurrence (being the name as the pattern is name-phone num-email and **we always search by name**), instead it only makes it incredibly slow to the point i get a timeout message from the server. I've been trying various solutions but have been out of luck.

Any ideas? Am i doing something wrong?

Thanks.

(*Original heavily edited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did I understand you right that something like this happens?

```
<a href="mailto:<b>email@domain</b>"><b>email@domain</b></a>
```

Why don't you put  tags into search results first, and only then apply "mailto:" anchors to emails? Added 's would be easy to filter out in the patter on that second step.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what happens. I tried replacing after it was tagged but then it wouldn't match, for example if the email was paul.surname@domain it would so <b>paul</b><a href="mailto:surname@domain </etc>. What do you mean by added 's? Also, i thought of including a PHP strip_tags piece of code inside the HTML mailto code but it prints as plain text, fails to see it as PHP.

Comment: So only name bits are made bold, not whole email addresses? It's a bit different then. You basically need your second "bold" regexp to happen only outside of HTML tags. Here is a similar case for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10539617/454266

Comment: Nevermind i turned my while() into an if() and it does it only once per entry, doesn't fix my problem entirely but does the job at the moment. However, your link was indeed very useful and could have helped a lot therefore i will accept your answer, thanks.